# How to clear dropdown box that is dependent on another dropdown box (html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I have a form with 2 dropdown boxes, box A and box B. Box A has 5 items, and depending on what item is selected, box B populates. This is working fine except for one issue:

If you select item 1 in Box A, Box B populates with 3 elements.
If you select item 2 in Box A, Box B populates with 8 elements.
(..and so on for all the 5 items in Box A..)

The problem arises if I go back and select item 1 in Box A (after say having previously selected item 2 in Box A), Box B will populate with the 3 elements for item 1 in Box A, but it will also show 5 extra elements belonging to item 2 of Box A.

My question is, how can I code it so that these extra elements that belong to item 2 of Box A dont show up? I tried to reset all options using the following code, but it doesnt work because it clears everything when all I want is for it to clear the extra elements:

```
for (a in select.options) { select.options.remove(0); }
```

Please note the number of elements in Box B is variable for each item in Box A.

Can someone please help solve this riddle?

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
      
     
        switch (listindex)
        {
        case "manual" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("OPEN","open");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("DELIVERED","delivered");
            break;
        case "online" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("OPEN","open");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("DELIVERED","delivered");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("SHIPPED","shipped");
            break;
        case "academic" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("Thesis/Dissertation","thesis");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("Study/Research/White paper","paper");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("Journal Article for Publication","article");
            document.getElementById("status").options[4]=new Option("Symposium/Conference Materials","conf");
            document.getElementById("status").options[5]=new Option("Response to Peer Reviewer Comments ","peerreview");
            document.getElementById("status").options[6]=new Option("Essay","essay");
            document.getElementById("status").options[7]=new Option("Translation","translation");
            break;
        case "medres" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("Thesis/Dissertation","medthesis");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("Study/Research/White paper","medpaper");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("Symposium/Conference Materials","medconf");
            document.getElementById("status").options[4]=new Option("Journal Article for Publication","medpub");
            document.getElementById("status").options[5]=new Option("Response to Peer Reviewer Comments ","medpeerreview");
            document.getElementById("status").options[6]=new Option("Grant proposal","grant");
            document.getElementById("status").options[7]=new Option("Translation","translation");
            break;
        case "business" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("Business, Marketing, or Sales Document","busdoc");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("Magazine Article / Blog","blog");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("Website/ Online Ad Copy","website");
            document.getElementById("status").options[4]=new Option("Translation","btranslation");
            break;
        case "jobseeker" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("Personal Letter / Application","jobapp");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("Cover Letter","coverletter");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("CV/Resume","cv");             
            break;
        case "other" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("Type of Writing Not Listed","other1");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("Other - additional services","other2");
            break;     
        }return true;
      
          
    }
</script>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
      <label for="type"> type ? </label>
      
            <select id="source" name="source" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="manual">MANUAL</option>
        <option value="online">ONLINE</option>
        <option value="academic">  Academic  </option>
        <option value="medres"> Medical/Research </option>
        <option value="business"> Business </option>
        <option value="jobseeker"> Job Seeker </option>
        <option value="other"> Other/Not sure </option> 
        </select>
    </div>
       <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
      <label for="type"> document </label>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="status" id="status"><option value="">Select status</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <select id="status" name="status">
            <option value="open">OPEN</option>
            <option value="delivered">DELIVERED</option>
            <option value="thesis" >Thesis/Dissertation</option>
            <option value="paper" >Study/Research/White paper</option>
            <option value="article" >Journal Article for Publication</option>
            <option value="conf" >Symposium/Conference Materials</option>
            <option value="essay" >Student Essay</option>
            <option value="pub" >Journal Article for Publication</option>
            <option value="peerreview" >Response to Peer Reviewer Comments </option>
            <option value="busdoc" >Business, Marketing, or Sales Document</option>
            <option value="blog" >Magazine Article / Blog</option>
            <option value="website" >Website / Online Ad Copy</option>
            <option value="translation" >Translation</option>
            <option value="jobapp" >Personal Letter / Application</option>
            <option value="coverletter" >Cover Letter</option>
            <option value="cv" >CV/Resume</option>
            <option value="other1" >Type of Writing Not Listed</option>
            <option value="other2" >Other - additional services</option>
               
        </select>
        </noscript>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could clear it, then re-add the items you want.

Comment: basically i want to clear box b before repopulating it....but how to do that?

Comment: Clear Box B the same way you do Box A

Comment: I dont clear Box A. Ive added the code, maybe that helps clarify the issue.